# quixel Bridge texture

Tags: modeling, texturing, export, add-on, import

I tried to export a plant model on bridge but it looks odd on blender, it looks like it has no texture[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in the nodes in the shader window each image texture is in the right place. Specular -> Specular, Normal -> Normal, etc. Also, turn clearcoat off. The reason for this is that for 3.0 onward Blender versions, Bridge's plugin is slightly buggy. Until they fix it, you have to manually fix all imported object's materials.

More info here: https://help.quixel.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4413712611857-Textures-looking-glossy-when-importing-to-Blender-3-0-from-Bridge